# Packages in Data Collector folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What are those in the *Data Collector* folder ?  I tried to delete some and got the message that it was conflicting with some reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those packages are related to [Management Data Warehouse](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306(v=sql.105).aspx).

If you open SQL Server Management Studio you will find a node 'Data Collection' where you can right click to configure data collection and also have access to some historical reports about server activity.

Have a look at [System Data Collection Sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964725(v=sql.105).aspx) where for example it states:

> The Query Activity collector type collects data by using the
>   QueryActivityCollect.dtsx SSIS package, and uploads data by using the
>   QueryActivityUpload.dtsx SSIS package.

For more information see [Data Collector Architecture and Processing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677355%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I'm not sure how you got to a point where you get 2 versions of each package (where one is appended by (1)). I tried reproducing that by enabling/disabling collection or creating a new MDW but maybe you got into that state by upgrading and then re-enabling data collection or something.